# Writing content of HTML table into PDF doc using iTextSharp in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, pdf-generation, itext

I have an HTML table stored in a string. I want to write that string into a PDF document using iTextSharp library. Please suggest the approach. Below is the table I want to write in a PDF file

```
<table>
<tr>
        <th>test</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>ABCD</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <th>test 2</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>XYZ</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its is possible.
try this.

```
    //HTMLString = Pass your Html , fileLocation = File Store Location
    public void converttopdf(string HTMLString, string fileLocation)
    {
        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();

        List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(HTMLString), null);
        for (int k = 0; k < htmlarraylist.Count; k++)
        {
            document.Add((IElement)htmlarraylist[k]);
        }

        document.Close();
    }
```

Comment: means generated pdf file You want to download on your system?

Comment: I got the solution, Thank you for the help.

Comment: this will show error in my page.. can you tell me which dll we can use on it

Comment: use 5.4.1 and download from (http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/itextsharp/iTextSharp-5.4.1/)

Comment: Is this free for commercial use ?